# How many people were killed by Protestant Inquisition-style tribunals?

Tags: catholicism, history, protestantism, persecution, inquisition

It is relatively easy to find estimates for the number of people killed during the Catholic Inquisition; one just needs to check the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquisition#Statistics), to see several estimates of the number of people killed.

However, there are several historical references to Protestant Inquisition-style tribunals, e.g. in Scotland. Furthermore, there are also historical references showing that even among different Protestant currents, Protestants were [killed](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/apologetics/protestantism/protin.htm).

I am looking for estimates of how many Christians (Protestants and Catholics) were killed in newly Protestant countries. Please provide references in support of your answer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43815/how-many-people-were-killed-by-protestant-inquisition-style-tribunals-asking-fo

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because new answers should better go to the version on History.SE which already has some. While not off-topic, the fact that the same question on History.SE attracted more answers shows that it is better suited there. Again, if you have a new answer, please go to the History.SE version, which is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Yes, this question is a duplicate which appeared in the SE History section.